# Android setup scrollview with relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have next code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/cm_diameter"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/from"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

The parameters that I am using are connected to relative layout.

I want to wrap this text views (I have another views as well) using scroll view.

My image shows the scroll view (green view) and below the scroll view some another container (black view). How can I achieve this result?

I've tried to use liner layout in scroll view but it has different result that I expected.

[image]

Comment: +1000 Nice background.

Comment: So you want the green area to scroll with the black area always at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @user2145222 Thanks. The black area does not scroll with scroll. The black area is under the scroll view.

Comment: "I want to wrap this text views (I have another views as well) using scroll view." What is exactly you want? could you clarify it?

Comment: @hieuxit I meant I have few views that I want to put to the scroll view but using relative layout. Under scroll view I want to have another view.

Comment: have you used ScrollView yet? (You bring the parent tag of green view into ScrollView tag)

Comment: I have use it. My problem with relative option that will no work in case if I use liner layout in scroll view. As I understand I always need to add liner layout (or relative) layout to the scroll view. But the property android:layout_marginTop="30dp" will no work in liner layout as I think. How can I config scroll view with relative layout in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what exactly android:layout_marginTop you put in. But as your design above I try to make a simple layout for this, and I think it work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff00ff00" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calculation" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dip"
            android:text="Item1"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
            android:text="Another text view for test"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
            android:text="Another text view for test"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
            android:text="Another text view for test"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
            android:text="Another text view for test"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
            android:text="Another text view for test"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
            android:text="Another text view for test"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
            android:text="Another text view for test"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
            android:text="Another text view for test"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:padding="20dip" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Add parameter" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Is it right?

Comment: And if you want have another space for the first view using marginTop. you should you <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:text="Calculation" />

do not use in the parent LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this example will get you started if I have understood you correctly. (Apologies if I have not.)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff00ff00"
>
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mainbody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:orientation="vertical"          
        >           
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Calculation"/>
        <!--Add the rest of you views here possibly changing 'mainbody'
        to be a RelativeLayout depending on the rest of your layout-->          
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>     
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My footer button"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for answer but as I think this parameters from my code will not work. I mean about android:layout_marginTop="30dp" etc

Comment: @Matrosov Alexander I am confused, adding the line 'android:layout_marginTop="30dp"' to the linearlayout named 'mainbody' works fine.  You can also add it to the scrollview itself if you wish as it is inside a relative layout in my example.